# calling ApiGatewayManagementApi.postToConnection() gives me 500 internal server error?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk

so I am trying to develop an aws websocket function using lambda. But it seems that whenever I try to call "postToConnection" it just gives me 500 internal server error.

Cloud watch also doesn't logs the error that I am receiving.

And what I'm receiving on the terminal once I send the message is this:

```
"{"message": "Internal server error", "connectionId":"xxx", "requestId":"xxx"}"
```

(Which doesn't give me any information at all)

This is my whole code on the lambda function.

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-west-2" });
var DDB = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: "2012-10-08" });
    
require('aws-sdk/clients/apigatewaymanagementapi');
    
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    var url_handler = event.requestContext.domainName + "/" + event.requestContext.stage;
    // var params = event.requestContext;
    // console.log(params);

    var scanParams = {
        TableName: "tbl-web-socket-connection",
        ProjectionExpression: "id"
    };
       
    DDB.scan(scanParams, function (err, data) {
        // callback(null, {
        //   statusCode: 200,
        //   body: "Data send to"
        // });
        if (err) {
            callback(null, {
                statusCode: 500,
                body: JSON.stringify(err)
            });
        } else {
            var apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
                apiVersion: "2018-11-29",
                endpoint: event.requestContext.domainName + "/" + event.requestContext.stage
            });
          
            var postParams = { 
                Data: JSON.parse(event.body).data
            };
            var count = 0;
    
            data.Items.forEach(function (element) {
                postParams.ConnectionId = element.id.S;
                console.log(postParams);
           
                apigwManagementApi.postToConnection(postParams, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                    // API Gateway returns a status of 410 GONE when the connection is no
                    // longer available. If this happens, we simply delete the identifier
                    // from our DynamoDB table.
      
                        if (err.statusCode === 410) {
                            console.log("Found stale connection, deleting " + postParams.connectionId);
                            DDB.deleteItem({ TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
                                Key: { connectionId: { S: postParams.connectionId } } });
                        } else {
                            console.log("Failed to post. Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                        }
                    } else {
                        count++;
                    }
                });
            });
 
            callback(null, {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: "Data send to " + count + " connection" + (count === 1 ? "" : "s")
            });
        }
    });
};
```

The aws-sdk is also updated, I declared it on a lambda layer and that's what I'm using.

Any idea what's causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a timeout, the dynamodb loops through all of the records which is causes timeout.

It looks like the cloudwatch was really logging the error, but I was just too focused on the terminal error which gives me the 500, Internal Server Error.

To fix this, just go to the lambda function and increase the time limit.

Comment: How long did you set the timeout? I'm not even looping through Dynamo and my post_to_connection (using Python boto3) is also timing out even though the time limit is 10 seconds.